# rails home page route is not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have created welcome controller and updated route file

```html
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get 'welcome/index'
  root 'welcome#index'
end
```

But I'm getting this error.

[image]

Comment: Error say that you are trying to access something that does not exist on given path. I do not thing it's about your route. Do you have `application.css` on your assets folder?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @Engr.HasanuzzamanSumon yes i have application.css file in assets folder

Comment: @mudasobwa  my question is how can i get rid of this error and display my home page

Comment: remove js and css link tag from application layout and see what you are getting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `root` does not really map to somewhere. Suppose you have a `welcome_controller` and a method `index` inside, then do:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root :to => 'welcome#index'
  get 'welcome/index'
end
```

I looked at your photo and found the error was in `stylesheet_link_tag`. You probably have no file/folder named `application` in `vendor/assets/stylesheets` folder. So remove that line or change file name to something in your `vendor/assets/`.

Comment: yes i have welcome_controller and index method,  i tried your code but still same error

Comment: `root 'welcome#index'`  is just shorthand of `root :to => 'welcome#index'`http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#using-root

Comment: Yes, vendor/assets/  folder don't have css or js file, i removed both tags and it works. Thanks